# Asp.net url routing traps asmx web service call

Tags: asp.net, routes, asmx

I have an Asp.Net 4.0 Web Forms project that uses url routing for user friendly urls, i.e hiding aspx-pages behind clear text urls.

In this project we have an asmx web service that serves some jQuery controls on the pages. Everything has worked fine so far on development machines and the internal testing site but now when we installed the project on a production site the asmx calls are trapped by the routing code.

We have a catch all route that is added last that shows the Not found -page.

When I open the web service on the server (http://localhost/service.asmx?op=MyWebMethod), enter some values and click Invoke I get the Not found page. The url that Invoke opens is http://localhost/service.asmx/MyWebMethod so it's all quite logical (service.asmx looks like a directory) but I don't understand how this can work on all other installations of the same project.

The production server is Windows 2008 Server R2 Standard, the project is Asp.net 4.0 and I haven't registered any StopRoutingHandler for asmx-files.

The web.config files are identical between the internal testing site and the production site and the machine.config -files haven't been touched to my knowledge.

Comment: Is the behavior the same when you're using a real client application and not the browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
routes.Add(new Route("{resource}.asmx/{*pathInfo}", new StopRoutingHandler()));
```

Comment: Yes, this works. I'm not sure why I didn't need to set it for it to work on my own machine.